# Need regex to ignore the whole line which contain #

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I need help in creating the regex to ignore the line which contain #
my regex : \s*sqlplus\s*$/gI

my regex : \s*sqlplus\s*$/gI
current i am able to avoid which sqlplus contain -s.
eg: sqlplus -s $username -this will not be kicked by my regex.

```
   SQLPLUS   $               -- true
```

RegExr sqlplus  $     -- true

#           sqlplus   -s $       -- false

#---   sqlplus   $               -- false

```
   SQLPLUS    -s    $        -- false
   sqlplus    -s    $        -- false
```

I want to avoid the line which contain # in beginning of line or before sqlplus and -s after sqlplus.

Comment: I suspect `gawk` will be very handy here: `gawk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} !/^[[:space:]]*#/ && !/sqlplus[[:space:]]*-s/ && /sqlplus/' file > newfile`. See [online demo](https://ideone.com/CA0P9a).

Comment: I can't tell what's the input from the output from  the code in your question. If you can tidy it up to clearly show the sample input and expected output then we can help you do whatever it is your trying to do concisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

`(?!.*?#.*?sqlplus.*?$)(?!^.*?sqlplus\s*-s.*?$)(?=^.*?sqlplus.*?$)^.*$`

[This is a demo.](https://regex101.com/r/XoqYay/1)

Comment: You can't use a non-POSIX regex in `sed`. E.g. it does not support lookarounds.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Do you know the "sed" online test website?

Comment: OP included the `sed` tag but didn't ask for `sed`-only answers, your regex could potentially be used by GNU `grep` with its `-P` flag. To test a `sed` command you could use any `bash` online interpreter such as https://ideone.com/, but as Wiktor said that won't work as `sed` only supports BRE and ERE, not PCRE.

Comment: @OliverHao you can use https://ideone.com/ or https://repl.it/ and choose `bash` .. which would give access to whatever implementation is supported

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
sed '/^#/d;/sqlplus -s/d'
```

explanation

```
/^#/d             # delete all lines starting with #
/sqlplus -s/d     # delete all lines that contain 'sqlplus -s'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ grep -Eiv '^#|sqlplus\s+-s' file
SQLPLUS   $               -- true
RegExr sqlplus $ -- true

$ sed -E '/^#|sqlplus\s+-s/Id' file
SQLPLUS   $               -- true
RegExr sqlplus $ -- true
```

The above were both run on this input file and use GNU tools:

```
$ cat file
SQLPLUS   $               -- true
RegExr sqlplus $ -- true
# sqlplus -s $ -- false
#--- sqlplus $ -- false
SQLPLUS    -s    $        -- false
sqlplus    -s    $        -- false
```

If that's not all you need then please update your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output.